# Split dataframe according to common consecutive sequences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, sequence

Let's consider this DataFrame :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"type" : ["dog", "cat", "whale", "cat", "cat", "lion", "dog"],
                   "status" : [False, True, True, False, False, True, True],
                   "age" : [4, 6, 7, 7, 1, 7, 5]})
```

It looks like that :

```
    type  status  age
0    dog   False    4
1    cat    True    6
2  whale    True    7
3    cat   False    7
4    cat   False    1
5   lion    True    7
6    dog    True    5
```

I want to split this dataframe according to **consecutive identical values** in the column status.
The result is stored in a list.

Here i write the expected result manually :

```
result = [df.loc[[0],:], df.loc[1:2,:], df.loc[3:4,:], df.loc[5:6,:]]
```

So result[0] is this dataframe:

```
  type  status  age
0  dog   False    4
```

result[1] is this dataframe:

```
    type  status  age
1    cat    True    6
2  whale    True    7
```

result[2] is this dataframe:

```
  type  status  age
3  cat   False    7
4  cat   False    1
```

result[3] is dataframe:

```
   type  status  age
5  lion    True    7
6   dog    True    5
```

What is the most efficient way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do

```
s = df.status.ne(df.status.shift())
result = [ y for _ , y in df.groupby(s.cumsum())]
#result[0]
#Out[69]: 
#  type  status  age
#0  dog   False    4
```

Comment: This is really smart. Impressive :). Explanation - df.status.shift() shifts downward df.status column. df.status.ne generates a new Series where the first element of each sequence is True and rest are false. Running cumsum gives cumulative sum, and thus generates incrementing integer for each group. Running groupby on these integer gives the group.